# IIS throws connection timeout error?

Tags: iis

when tries to upload a file of size 1GB in IIS 6.0, it throws Request Timeout issue.

Does any one has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to move the request to an ftp server ?

You can change the connection timeout, but for 1GB ? it will kill you server eventually.